# TrixBox SIP Peer and it's extension

Tags: centos, sip, voip, asterisk

I am totally new to this PBX, I really don't know what is it and I wanna learn it ASAP, I've created an SIP peer and an SIP user, in Extensions.conf I need the code to route all outbound calls to that SIP Peer (which is a gsm gateway of GoIP). Here're my files 
Extensions.conf :

```
[goip]
exten => 1,1,Wait(1)
exten => 1,n,Answer
exten => 1,n,Playback(hello-world)
exten => 1,n,Wait(2)
exten => 1,n,Hangup
```

User Configuration in Sip_additional.conf:

```
[400]
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
type=friend
secret=aneestech01
qualify=yes
port=5060
pickupgroup=
permit=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
nat=yes
mailbox=400@default
host=dynamic
dtmfmode=rfc2833
dial=SIP/400
context=from-internal
canreinvite=no
callgroup=
callerid=device <400>
accountcode=
call-limit=50
```

Peer Configuration in SIP.conf:

```
[gsm1]
canreinvite=no
context=goip
dtmfmode=rfc2833
fromuser=gsm1
host=dynamic
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
allow=g729
insecure=port,invite
secret=gsm1
type=friend
defaultname=gsm1
```

Please note that both my GSM Gateway and My SIP client are connected to the asterisk pbx successfully, The thing I request now is that whenever I dial a number from sip client, it should be dialed from the gsm gateway, if you need any kind of additional info please post a comment and you'll get a reply soon

Comment: I need the code to... Is not a proper question.

Comment: thanks but the problem has already been solved below I have posted the answer which worked for me, I wanna ask another question but StackOverFlow wont let me :\ Can you help me with that please?

Answer (score 0):

You need context like:

```
[from-internal]

exten => _X.,1,Dial(SIP/gsm1,,)
```

But i highly recomend you read some book for beginners like "asterisk the future of telephony"

Comment: okay, so do I have to put the two commas in the brackets you typed like (SIP/gsm1",,") ? Please tell me asap

Comment: I have made this and it is working like a charm exten => _X.,1,Dial(SIP/goip/${EXTEN}) asterisk is now forwarding to the gsm gateway of GoIP, now I am getting service unavailable error, can you please give me a clue on what is it?

Comment: Hard to guess what is going on there. You have to check the SIP trace and study how your gsm gateway and asterisk communicate each other. For this you need to turn on asterisk SIP debug using command: `sip set debug on` (depend on the version). To study this you need the knowledge of SIP and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Guys This worked for me:
`[from-internal]`
`exten => _X.,1,Dial(SIP/gsm1/${EXTEN})`